# hide a div if empty with jquery

Tags: jquery

This block of code belongs to a joomla module that posts articles.The problem is that inside this div

`<div class="ns2-row <?php echo $j==0 ? 'ns2-first' : '' ?> <?php echo $j%2 ? 'ns2-even' : 'ns2-odd' ?>">`

Its getting posted the article and 4 more divs that are completly empty. Theese divs are getting padding + border from css. ( they use the same class as the article so i cant just display:none em ).I dont like the output and i would like to remove any div that is empty.My first touch with jquery was today and after some searching i reached to the below code that dont seem to work.
I pasted only the block of code i want to edit.

```
<div class="ns2-page <?php echo $anim_class; ?>">
  <div class="ns2-page-inner">
  <?php for($j=0;$j<$article_row;$j++, $i++): ?>
    <div class="ns2-row <?php echo $j==0 ? 'ns2-first' : '' ?> <?php echo $j%2 ? 'ns2-even' : 'ns2-odd' ?>">
        <div class="ns2-row-inner">
        <script>
        $('div').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).html()).length == 0;
        }).hide();
        </script>
```

i tried it and as `return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';` but also nothing happened ? i do something wrong ?

Comment: Cannot you check instead if article (or whatever DIV) is empty server side and then not generate it? This is how to should be done but i don't know much drupal. Maybe i completly misunderstand your issue

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this:

```
$('div:empty').hide();
```

#### [@ jQuery docs for `:empty` selector-](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

Comment: that empty divs i wanna get rid of , have another 1 empty div inside them ! so if im not mistaken this would be a children for the parent div  and the above code wouldnt work, right?

Comment: `$('div')` is the selector which always returns a collection, so in your case wherever it finds empty div will be get hidden.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('div').each(function(){
  if(!$(this).children().length){
   $(this).hide();
  }

});
```

or

```
 $('div').filter(function(){
    $(this).children().length==0;
 }).hide();
```

Comment: it doesnt work also :( maybe i dont put the code in the right block ? for me seems kinda right ,because every time the for loops gonna create a new div so the script should run after to check if it is empty.